# Rotation bmp image c++ by 90 degrees

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, image, multidimensional-array

I want to rotate the images by angles that are multiples of 90 degrees. I use a simple pixel swap for this.

When I write such code:

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.Height(); y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < image.Width(); x++) {
   image[x + y * image.Width()] = origin[ x * origin.Width() + origin.Width() -  y + 1];
    }
 }
```

The image is flipped with a strange artifact:
[image]

The original image looks like this:[image]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That `+ 1` looks wrong to me. If I understand the math correctly, when both `x` and `y` are 0, this will pull some pixel from the second row, and not the first one.

Comment: Note that you may have to take into account stride and pixel format.

Answer (score 0):

**If you change this line:**

```
image[x + y * image.Width()] = origin[ x * origin.Width() + origin.Width() -  y + 1];
```

**to be:**

```
image[x + y * image.Width()] = origin[ x * origin.Width() + origin.Width() -  y - 1];   // minus 1 instead of plus 1
```

**It will solve your artifact problem**.

This is because in order to mirror a coordinate in the range `(0 .. dimension-1)`, you need to apply:

```
<mirrored_coord> = <dimension> - <org_coord> - 1
```

**Note**: This solution assumes that the class holding `image` and `origin` has `operator[]` that returns a reference to a single pixel object (probably a 3 channel object).
Also assumed that your images do not have padding, i.e. the stride in elements is equal to the width.